# Do directives avoid layout trashing?

Tags: angular

I wonder if `Renderer2` somehow has mechanism to avoid layout trashing. Let's have sample directive which relocate tooltip if there's no more space on screen:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[fooDirective]',
  exportAs: 'fooDirective'
})
export class FooDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.onResize();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  public onResize(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.left = null;
    this.el.nativeElement.style.top = null;

    const bounds = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (windowWidth < bounds.right) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'left', `calc(100% - ${bounds.right - windowWidth}px)`);
    }

    if (windowHeight < bounds.bottom) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'top', `calc(0px - ${bounds.bottom - windowHeight}px)`);
    }
  }
}
```

There are two conditions in `onResize` which could be overlaped with for example https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom but I wonder if it's necessary? Maybe angular2 handle this itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, renderer executes your task immediately as can be seen [from the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L182):

```
class DefaultDomRenderer2 implements Renderer2 {
      setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags: RendererStyleFlags2): void {
        if (flags & RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase) {
          el.style.setProperty(
              style, value, !!(flags & RendererStyleFlags2.Important) ? 'important' : '');
        } else {
          el.style[style] = value;
        }
      }
```